# Display parallel Clojure array and range values

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

The following function takes a range of Celcius temperatures, converts them to Fahrenheit, and puts them into an array.

```
(defn build-f [size]
    (map float (vec (map  #(+(/(* % 9)5)32) (range size)))))
```

My goal is then to print each converted temperature in the following format:

```
C[0] = 32 F
C[1] = 33.8 F
...
```

The format doesn't really matter. I'm new to functional programming and still thinking the OOP

way.
I tried to use the map function to do that. What should I go with? Map, reduce, for, doall?

So far I came up with the following:

1. display-format function should display something like this `C[0] =`. I'm not sure how to place that [index] there though.

   (defn display-format [t-scale]
   (println t-scale "=" ))
2. display-array function should use the map function to apply display-format
   function to the array.

   (defn display-array [t-scale array]
   (map (display-format t-scale) array))

Am I going in the right direction?

Update:
Here the code I was going for. Hope it helps someone.

```
(defn display-table [from-scale array to-scale]
  (map #(println (str from-scale "[" %1 "] = " %2 " " to-scale)) 
  (range (count array)) array))
```

Comment: SO is for concrete programming problems.  Please implement the function like you think it's OK and if you get errors, add the code to the question and what errors there are. Otherwise I am not clear about what you are asking. "Will this code work?" Why not try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation). Especially study the Clojure CheatSheet.

For your purposes, study

1. `doseq` for looping over the values to print output
2. `format` for using `%d` and similar output formatting options
3. `str` for concatenating strings
4. I'd suggest making a function `celcius->farenheit` and then calling that in a loop.  Call `double` on the input arg and it will avoid any worries about int vs float all the way downstream.
5. I always prefer `mapv` over `map` to eliminate problems from laziness

Enjoy!